# C# topics names for multicast

Tags: c#, networking, multicast

do you know if in C# is it possible to create a communication between client and server using  TOPIC names via multicast?

Is there any class or free messaging system able to do that?
Essentially a server open a communication and send data to a channel represented by a Topic name i.e. a String e.g. "MAIN_DATA" and all clients (multiple since it is multicast) that subscribed that topic can get data out of it.

Regards

Comment: It might be worth telling us what TOPIC is. At least me has never heard of it, and it's a tricky thing to search for :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming by **Topic** you mean a multicast-**group**. Since it is possible for different clients to register themselves to different groups, and tx/rx messages accordingly.

[Source](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/internetworking/technology/handbook/IP-Multi.html):

> Multicast Group Concept
>   Multicast is based on the concept of a group. An arbitrary group of receivers expresses an interest in receiving a particular data stream. This group does not have any physical or geographical boundaries—the hosts can be located anywhere on the Internet. Hosts that are interested in receiving data flowing to a particular group must join the group using IGMP. Hosts must be a member of the group to receive the data stream.

This article has examples on how to join/leave a [multicast group](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/multicast.aspx).

All clients registered to a specific group would send/receive data being tx/rx to that group.

[image]

[Fig1: Source](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2009/07/multicast-ip-udp-igmp-multi-homed.html)

Also, see [Emcaster](http://code.google.com/p/emcaster/)

> The library provides a powerful api for publishing and subscribing to reliable messages over Pragmatic General Multicast or Udp Multicast. The framework is designed for high throughput and low latency.
>
> The library is designed for clustering, application monitoring, and high performance, reliable data publishing.